# how to summarize data based on a field in a row

Tags: bash, data-processing

In bash, how can I read in a large .csv file and summarize the data? I need to get totals for each person.

example input:

```
joey    4
joey    3
joey    4
joey    6
paul    7
paul    3
paul    1
paul    4
trevor  5
trevor  6
henry   7
mark    8
mark    9
tom 0
```

It should end up like this in the end:

```
joey    17
paul    15
trevor  11
henry   7
mark    17
tom 2
```

Comment: This can easily be achieved using awk. Use an array with a key for each person, i.e. `a[$1]`. How does tom end up with 2 bonus points?

Answer (score 0):

```
list=`your example input | awk '{print $1}' | uniqe`
```

it gives You something like this:

```
joey
paul
trevor
henry
mark
tom
```

Now let's make a two for loops:

```
for i in $list
do
     for j in `$list | grep $i | awk '{print $2}'`
     do
     counter=$counter+$j
     done 
echo "$i $j"
done
```

First loop is going by the names and second one is just counting results for each name. Guess it should work, and it's quite easy way.